# Are Wizard spells also Paladin Spells when provided by Sword of the Arcane Order?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, paladin

**Background**

I have a [Paladin](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm) that reveres [Mystra](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Mystra), and would like to be take as much advantage of spells as possible. The DM has allowed the Serenity feat - which is excellent for reducing *MAD*. Of course, you can't really take Paladin spells seriously without taking the Battle Blessing feat.

**Dilemma**

If I was rather unsatisfied with the Paladin spell list, and decided on taking the Sword of the Arcane Order feat, would the wizard spells that I gain in my Paladin spell slots still be considered Paladin spells? What effect would taking the Winter's Champion feat have if I selected Sword of the Arcane Order?

---

**Revision Due to Comments**

If I took the Magical Training feat, I would gain a spellbook, and three 0-level spells. With Sword of the Arcane Order, I would not be restricted from "borrowing from someone else's spellbook," correct?

---

**Feat References**

- **Sword of the Arcane Order**

  > You can use your paladin and ranger spell slots to prepare wizard spells.
- **Battle Blessing**

  > You can cast most of your paladin spells faster than normal.
- **Winter's Champion**

  > When you gain this feat, you may add the 1<sup>st</sup>-, 2<sup>nd</sup>-, 3<sup>rd</sup>-, and 4<sup>th</sup>-level spells granted by the Cold and Winter domains as paladin spells of the same levels.
- **Serenity**

  > Use your Wisdom bonus in place of your Charisma bonus for purposes of divine grace, lay on hands, smite evil, and turn undead.
- **Magical Training**

  > You have a spellbook with three 0-level spells of your choice from the sorcerer/wizard list. You prepare your spells exactly as a wizard
  >   does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31683/discussion-between-miniman-and-pitzy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sword of the Arcane Order**: Your spells are Wizard spells, not Paladin spells. They are arcane, not divine. This is because there is no specification that they count as Paladin spells. They may be consuming your Paladin/Ranger spell slots, but they still are Wizard spells, and when cast, they treat you as a Wizard with a caster level equal to your Paladin/Ranger/Wizard levels, added together. **Take note that these are arcane spells, and are subject to Arcane Spell Failure**. :(

**Battle Blessing**: This applies to Paladin spells, unfortunately, and have no bearing on the spells prepared via Sword of the Arcane Order.

**Winter's Champion**: The specified spells from the Cold and Winter domains are now in your Paladin spell list, and you may prepare them accordingly as Paladin spells (now subject to Battle Blessing). These spells are not automatically prepared, however.

**Serenity**: Nice choice for a Wisdom-focused Paladin. ;)

---

Please note that Sword of the Arcane Order does not automatically grant the Wizard spell list. **Sword of the Arcane Order allows you to *prepare* Wizard spells, but you need a spellbook to base your preparation on**. Essentially, your choice of Wizard spells is restricted to those in the spellbook available to you.

Also, if you don't have an arcane class that prepares a spellbook, you will always be treated as *borrowing* a spellbook (even if you actually own the spellbook). This means that you will be required to make Spellcraft checks in preparing each spell via Sword of the Arcane Order.

---

> Revision Due to Comments
>
> If I took the Magical Training feat, I would gain a spellbook, and
>   three 0-level spells. With Sword of the Arcane Order, I would not be
>   restricted from "borrowing from someone else's spellbook," correct?

Please be reminded that **Magical Training can only be taken at 1st level**. That said, unfortunately, the Magical Training feat restricts your learning to those three 0-level spells, and the Paladin has no 0-level spell slots, so you won't be able to use those with Sword of the Arcane Order.

Also, **Magical Training does not grant the ability to prepare/write any other spell in the spellbook**. It restricts you to those three 0-level spells. You will really need at least a 1-level dip into the Wizard class to gain the spellbook preparation/writing ability. Yes, you do *own* the spellbook, but to copy other spells into it requires the special ability of the Wizard, and this ability is not granted by the Magical Training feat. Even if another Wizard writes the spell into your spellbook, you will still need to decipher it and prepare it like a borrowed spell because you didn't write it yourself.

Comment: I know I would have a spellbook, however, I can't replicate the entire text of the feat because it isn't OGL.

Comment: Good to know. Please take note that unless you have an arcane class that can prepare your own spellbook, you will always be treated as **borrowing** a spellbook, and will always need a Spellcraft check to prepare every Wizard spell via SOTAO. :)

Comment: @Ruut : Updated the answer to include Magical Training. ;)

Comment: @Ruut Check out the *Spellbook* entry of the Wizard class description, as well as the *Arcane Magical Writings* entry of Magic Overview > Arcane Spells, both available in the d20SRD. It is not the Scribe Scroll feat. ;)